# Difficulty understanding the colorful numbers concept

Tags: computer-science

According to an example (https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/colorful-numbers/) :

Given Number : 3245
Output : Colorful
Number 3245 can be broken into parts like 
3 2 4 5 32 24 45 324 245.
this number is a colorful number, since product of every digit of a sub-sequence are different.
That is, 3 2 4 5 (3*2)=6 (2*4)=8 (4*5)=20, (3*2*4)= 24 (2*4*5)= 40

Given Number : 326
Output : Not Colorful.
326 is not a colorful number as it generates 3 2 6 (3*2)=6 (2*6)=12.

It doesn't make sense. What am I missing?
It says that PRODUCT of EVERY DIGIT of a SUBSET is DIFFERENT.

But the products for the subsets of  326 are also different since they equal  6 and 12 (as shown in the example above).
And 6 != 12.

Hopefully somebody can explain this like I'm 5 to me.

Comment: You should state a definition of colorful.  What is ELI5?  It reads like explain.  We are more formal than that here. "But the products for 326 are also different since 6 and 12." is not a sentence and I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: My Apology.  ELI5 = Explain like I'm 5.

Comment: 6 is also the product of a 1-element subset. To elaborate: In the 3245 case, all *nine* products are different. In the 326 case, there are *five* products: 3, 2, 6, 6, 12, of which two are the same.

Comment: So I assume that the example should be more detailed and mention all nine and five products ? Then it would indeed make immediate sense to me.

Comment: I would love to post a definition of colorful numbers but I am not able to find one which is strange in itself.

Comment: They are already listed right there in your question. "326 is not a colorful number as it generates **3** **2** **6** (3\*2) = **6** (2\*6) = **12**." (emphasis added)

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the fact that $6$ is a substring of $326$ and $6=3\cdot 2$ as Rahul says.  I think that is an answer, so I posted it CW.

Comment: Thank you. This and writing down everything helped me to finally understand it.
All the time I assumed that the initial digits are not being counted as products and it was only about minimum of 2 digits multiplied. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: But what is CW?

Comment: Yes , what is CW?

Comment: Community Wiki.  One can designate an answer that way and anybody can edit it.  You don't get credit for upvotes.  I use it when I steal an answer from somebody's comment, here from Rahul.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on this.